# Kafka bitnami:latest supports env varible which isn't mentioned in official docs

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, bitnami

As i know, default kafka message size is 1mb, at the moment i need increase it.

I found github issue, where people say how to fix it.

The result is configuration:

```
- KAFKA_MESSAGE_MAX_BYTES=100001200
```

The weirdes thing is that bitnami official docs doesn't have `KAFKA_MESSAGE_MAX_BYTES`, and it works for bitnami kafka latest - 3.0.0. (I know that using :latest is bad practice)

As i see there was something similar - `KAFKA_MAX_MESSAGE_BYTES` but was renamed to `KAFKA_CFG_MESSAGE_MAX_BYTES`

So, can anyone explain why do my bitnami kafka supports this unknown variable?) Or should i use another variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the variables we renamed from `KAFKA_*` to `KAFKA_CFG_*` several releases ago. They should both work, for now.

`max.message.bytes` is not the same as `message.max.bytes`, however. Only the latter is the broker config that you can set with an env-var.